# Need help understanding function pointer define in the following?

Tags: c++

Not sure what to make of the following and how to use it?
thx

```
class A;
typedef void (*CALLBACK)( A*, void* );
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? It's a pointer to a function returning `void` and taking an `A*` and a `void*` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a type definition defining the type `CALLBACK` as a function pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes an `A*` and a `void*` as parameters.

```
typedef void (*CALLBACK)(A*, void*);
void cb(A*, void*);
CALLBACK handler = cb;
...
A* obj = new A();
some_type data;
handler(obj, &data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes an `A *` followed by `void *`. Thus you could do

```
void f(A*, void*);
CALLBACK cbk = f;
// ...
A* a;
void *p;
cbk(a, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to a function returning `void` and taking an `A*` and a `void*` parameter. E.g.

```
void foo(A* a, void* v)
{
   ...
}

...

CALLBACK c = foo;
```